# here::here() is inserting a string "\u2068" before subdirectory name in my R project

Tags: r

I have no idea why this is happening, but it does prevent `here::here()` from performing reliably.

I execute the code

```
here::here("⁨data", "images", "r_squared_formula.png")
```

My output will read

`[1] "/Users/my_name/Documents/coding/project_name/\u2068data/images/my_image.png"`

My code will run if If I hardcode in the file path "/Users/my_name/Documents/coding/project_name/data/images/my_image.png" but I want to understand why this seemingly random insertion of "\u2068" is happening when I use `here()`.

My session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.3  backports_1.1.3 here_0.1        rprojroot_1.3-2 tools_3.5.3     yaml_2.2.0      knitr_1.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invisible Unicode character between `"` and `data`.

delete `"data"` and type it in again.